# java.io.File's .createNewFile() doesn't create a file

Tags: file, io

```
class FileClassOne {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    File myDir = new File(File.separator);
    System.out.println("myDir.getAbsolutePath() = " + myDir.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("myDir.isDirectory() = " + myDir.isDirectory());
    System.out.println("myDir.isFile() = " + myDir.isFile());
    System.out.println();

    myDir = new File(File.separator+"Java"+File.separator+"FilePartOne");
    System.out.println("myDir.getAbsolutePath() = " + myDir.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("myDir.isDirectory() = " + myDir.isDirectory());
    System.out.println("myDir.isFile() = " + myDir.isFile());
    System.out.println();

    File myFile = new File(myDir, "Temp.txt");
    System.out.println("myFile.getAbsolutePath() = " + myFile.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("myFile.isDirectory() = " + myFile.isDirectory());
    System.out.println("myFile.isFile() = " + myFile.isFile());
    System.out.println("myFile.exists() = " + myFile.exists());
    try { 
        myFile.createNewFile(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
```

Output:
myDir.getAbsolutePath() = C:\
myDir.isDirectory() = true
myDir.isFile() = false

myDir.getAbsolutePath() = C:\Java\FilePartOne
myDir.isDirectory() = false
myDir.isFile() = false

myFile.getAbsolutePath() = C:\Java\FilePartOne\Temp.txt
myFile.isDirectory() = false
myFile.isFile() = false
myFile.exists() = false
The system cannot find the path specified

This code if from an online tutorial that works in the video and it's copied verbatim. IDE is eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say its likely because of missing directories along the path "C:\Java\FilePartOne".

The statement:

```
myFile.createNewFile();
```

Will attempt to create a file on a given path, not create any missing directories. You therefore get the error "The system cannot find the path specified" if any directories are missing when executing the statement.

A quick way to fix this would be to either create the missing folders yourself or add the code below just before  myFile.createNewFile();.

```
myFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

Comment: Oh jeez. Yes the tut I was watching must have had the path already so I assumed .createNewFile() creates the dir as long as it was specified to the  File object. Thanks.